# Same Controller & Route with multiple URLs in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible for the same route, let's say addUser to be both a child of the users route and of the general route?

Users/addUser, general/addUser

While both use the same route, controller and so on?

I need basically the addUser screen to be an inner page (through outlet) in both the dashboard and the users list page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could create 2 separate routes - `users/addUser` and `general/addUser`, BUT keep `controller` and `template` the same for both of them. `Route` properties could be placed, for example, in a `Mixin` to keep your code DRY.

You can achieve this by specyfing [templateName](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_templateName) and [controllerName](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#property_controllerName) in second [Route](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html). In first route controller and template will be in correct place, in second, you have to tell Ember that they're in other place. Generating [Mixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html) in Ember CLI and adding it to both routes not to repeat code is the final point.

It's clean approach and you just need to keep 2 additional files(1 route, 1 mixin).